# Unexpectedly found nil when opening an UIImage

Tags: swift, uiimageview

I am developing a Walkthrough screen where I have added 3 instruction images which help the users to work with the application. The problem occurs, when I first launch the app I see only the labels with the "instruction tekst" , but below this label the user should also see the images. Maybe I am doing something wrong, attached I uploaded a picture of the error:
[image]

And here I upload the picture of the code I have used to transfer these picture to the TutorialPageContentHolderViewController:
[image]
I would be very thankful if you see my mistake, because I have been struggling with that the whole day.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu

Comment: Could you check if you have a value where you call `pageImages[index] as! String`?

Comment: no I do not have it, where should I add it?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the `imageFileName` variable in your first image is `nil` when you use it in

```
myImageView.image = UIImage(named: imageFileName)
```

When you assign it a value in the second screenshot it could be too late, as  `viewdidLoad` is loaded before that. You could check if this is true by manually assigning a valid value to `imageFileName` before using it and see if it works.

One simple way to fix it would be to add an initialiser to the view controller class, pass the filename as a parameter and store the filename in a local variable until you use it in `viewDidLoad`.

A second way would be to add a method to the page view controller as below (and remove the corresponding line from `viewDidLoad`):

```
func prepare(with filename:String) {
    myImageView.image = UIImage(named: filename)
}
```

and call it from the `pageTutorialAtIndex` method in your main view controller.

Comment: Added some hints on how to fix this in my answer.

Comment: @Dakata: please don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you solve your problem